# Jetty, JNDI, Postgresql: Class not found

Tags: java, postgresql, jetty, jndi, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to set up a JNDI DataSource in Jetty. In the start.ini file I have add the jetty-plus.xml file and the Options look like this:

```
OPTIONS=Server,resources,websocket,ext,plus,annotations
```

Then I'm adding the resource in my context file:

```
<New id="Traildevils" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg/>
    <Arg>jdbc/Traildevils</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="User">recom</Set>
            <Set name="Password">recom</Set>
            <Set name="DatabaseName">Traildevils</Set>
            <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
            <Set name="PortNumber">5432</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

The postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar file is in the WEB-INF/lib of my war file.

When I'm now trying to start the jetty I get the following error:

```
2012-04-12 12:58:09.723:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:Config error at 
<New id="Traildevils" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"><Arg/>
<Arg>jdbc/Traildevils</Arg>
<Arg>|???<New class="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource">
<Set name="User">recom</Set>
<Set name="Password">recom</Set>
<Set name="DatabaseName">Traildevils</Set>
<Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set><Set name="PortNumber">5432</Set></New>|??</Arg></New> 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar to `$JETTY_HOME/lib/ext`.

This is because jetty initializes the JNDI context before it loads the classes from your WAR.